# How is the r-value reference being passed in here?

Tags: c++

```
void test(vector<int> v) {
    for(int i:v) cout<< i<<" ";
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> v{ 1,2,3 };
    test(move(v));
    cout << "v is gone...."; 
}
```

I am new to move semantics and rvalue references. In the code above, the vector is printed. Clearly the move worked.

What I don't understand is how it worked. Why don't I have to define a function that takes in an rvalue reference? My best guess is the compiler is generating this automatically:

```
void test(vector<int>&& v) {
    for(int i:v) cout<< i<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector with an r-value reference to it:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};

std::vector<int> b = std::move(a); // Constructs b from r-value reference
```

This invokes `std::vector`'s move constructor, which basically just copies the data pointer from the first vector to the second vector.

When you invoke the function `void test(std::vector<int> v)` in your example, the same thing happens: the compiler calls `std::vector`'s move constructor, and creates a new vector in the stack space allocated for the parameter `v`. No functions are implicitly generated.

**The difference between** `void test(std::vector<int> v)`, **and** `void test(std::vector<int>&& v)`.

In the first case, you're passing the vector by value. That means that whenever you call `test`, the function calling `test` allocates space for a new vector on the stack before invoking `test`. It has to call `std::vector`'s constructor, and in the process, it either

- moves a vector;
- copies a vector; or
- magically constructs the vector in-place (this happens if you construct the vector at the site where you call `test`, for example in `test(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3})`)

On the other hand, `test(std::vector<int>&& v)` takes the argument by reference. This means that when you call this version of `test` by moving a variable, *no new vector gets created*. Whatever vector you give it is passed by reference, and as a result **any changes that `test(std::vector<int>&&)` makes to the vector will show up on the original.**

For example:

```
// Even though v is passed as an r-value reference, 
// v is never moved-from inside test(). An object is only moved-from
// If an r-value reference to it is used to construct a new object. 
void test(std::vector<int>&& v) {
    v.push_back(4); 
}

std::vector<int> myList = {1, 2, 3}; 
test(std::move(myList)); // Adds 4 to the end of myList

// Prints 1 2 3 4
for(int i : myList) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> My best guess is the compiler is generating this automatically

The only code a compiler will generate automatically is for constructors, assignment operators and destructors. And those have caveats. What's happening here is not about auto generated code. When you write `test(move(v))` (for some type `V`), that can be made to work in a couple of ways.

1. `test` accepts an argument of type `V&&`. That will happily bind to the rvalue reference you provided.
2. `test` accepts an argument of type `V const&`. Const lvlaue references bind to rvalue reference arguments too. That way old code that is not adjusted for move semantics can still work. A const lvlaue reference is a handy fallback.
3. `test` accepts a `V`. Here cases (1) and (2) can applied to the constructors of `V`.

In our specific case, `std::vector` has a move constructor ready to accept the reference you provided.

Comment: So, of the three cases you mentioned #3 applies here, right? So in the end will it be passed by const reference or by value?

Comment: @user3586940 - By value. But that value is constructed by calling a move constructor.